# MySQL LEFT JOIN with IF

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT r.*, d.rateName
FROM ratings r
LEFT JOIN rate_data d ON (r.rateID=d.rateID AND d.rateName != '')
ORDER BY r.rateTime DESC
```

This work fine. Now I have a second data table. Give a change to make this with an IF in one query, or is the only way to make two queries and merge the result?

I try to show you what I mean:

```
SELECT r.*, d.rateName
FROM ratings r
(IF r.isOther == 0)LEFT JOIN rate_data d ON (r.rateID=d.rateID AND d.rateName != '')
(ELSEIF r.isOther == 1)LEFT JOIN rate_data_other d ON (r.rateOtherID=d.rateOtherID AND d.rateName != '')
ORDER BY r.rateTime DESC
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Just use union: 

    <code> SELECT * FROM ( 
 (SELECT r.*, d.rateName
 FROM ratings r
LEFT JOIN rate_data d ON (r.rateID=d.rateID AND d.rateName != '')
WHERE r.isOther = 0 ) 
UNION (
SELECT r.*, d.rateName
 FROM ratings r
 LEFT JOIN rate_data_other d ON (r.rateOtherID=d.rateOtherID AND d.rateName != '')
  WHERE r.isOther = 1) 
  ) TMP
ORDER BY TMP.rateTime DESC </code>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT r.*, IF(r.isOther,do.rateName,d.rateName)
FROM ratings r
LEFT JOIN rate_data d ON (r.rateID = d.rateID AND d.rateName != '')
LEFT JOIN rate_data_other do ON (r.rateOtherID = do.rateOtherID AND do.rateName != '')
ORDER BY r.rateTime DESC;
```

Or

```
SELECT r.*, 
(CASE 
 WHEN r.isOther = 0 THEN d.rateName
 ELSE do.rateName
 END) as rateName
FROM ratings r
LEFT JOIN rate_data d ON (r.rateID = d.rateID AND d.rateName != '')
LEFT JOIN rate_data_other do ON (r.rateOtherID = do.rateOtherID AND do.rateName != '')
ORDER BY r.rateTime DESC;
```